# Visualizing arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a lage JPanel in my JFrame which contains arraylist of "Pages" - data type which extends JPanel, it defaultly contains JPanel "area", height equaling the cumulative one of it's children (which it has none by default), and BOX.filler (preffered height is full height of the "Page"). So, by default, the whole "Page" is filled with filler, which decreases as I add elements to "area".

Also, I have an array list which contain JPanels. They are elements which go onto "area". As I add them, when height of filler becomes zero, I create a new "Page" and move last element (which went "off bounds") onto it. Basically, it's supposed to work similar to MS Word.

Now the catch. User can add and remove those elements freely, from whichever part of the document. The question is, how can I add an element to a random spot on "area"? Addition will probably be made by invoking a keylistener attached to another element, so I will know between which two elements is the random one being put.

Is there a layout manager that can be used for this or should it be done another way?
Which way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you problem correctly, you are trying to insert a component at a certain position instead of appending it?

If that's your problem, you might want to use a BoxLayout and the add(component, index) method of java's swing containers. Of course you might again need to move some childrens to the following page, and recursively childrens of the following page to the one after that.

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AddAt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel one = new JLabel("one");
        JLabel two = new JLabel("two");
        JLabel between = new JLabel("between");

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(one);
        panel.add(two);
        panel.add(between, 1);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

results in:
[image: JFrame with panels in the right order]